# How to use a property view of a layout in another view in java code?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, view

I have 2 activity,("Mainactivity" and "NumbersActivity") and 2 layouts("activity_main.xml" and "activity_numbers.xml").
there is a "textview1",(by id:textview1_id)" in "activity_main.xml", and a "textview2",(by id:textview2_id) in "activity_numbers.xml".
I use API 16.
In "NumbersActivity", Below code not responding:

```
[codes are write in NumbersActivity]
TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1_id);
ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) textView1.getBackground();
int colorId = cd.getColor();
textView2.setBackgroundColor(colorId);
```

but not works.
How could use get and set color of textview2 from textview1?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a view that is not declared on the layout file in which your current activity has inflated.

This is, in your example, only `MainActivity` can find to the `R.id.textview1_id` as very likely has inflated the layout where that view exists, with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

Therefore, when inflating from `NumbersActivity` the `activity_numbers.xml` layout, it does not include the `textview1_id`. It only will be able to find the views declared within that XML file, in this case, the one with the id `textview2_id`.

The solution for you is to declare in the `activity_numbers.xml` the `textview1`, if that's what you need.

Comment: Problem is that you mentioned,so how could geto to reference of textview1_id while current activity is NumbersActivity ?

Comment: You would need to declare the `textview1_id` inside the `NumbersActivity` layout. But take in mind that will be a new textview instance, not the one existing in the other activity (MainActivity). 

Another solution might be using fragments, where it's easier to access already inflated views across activities and fragments, despite is not a good practice, I guess.

Comment: Thank you, but there is maybe a solution exist.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:
Inside MainActivity create this method

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
 MainActivity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(cd.getColor(), "colorID");
editor.apply();
```

and in your NumberActivity you can do this:

```
     SharedPreferences sharedPref = NumberActivity.getSharedPreferences(
    getInt(colorId, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot Return inside changecolor method

Comment: actually i make a correction in your code like this:     public int changeColorInFirstActivity(){
        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NumbersId);
        ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) textView1.getBackground();
        int colorId = cd.getColor();
        return colorId;
    } but still not working

Comment: after all corrections in your code and use it,not working

Comment: Ok, then you can use SharedPreferences to save colorId, and get it inside your NumberAcitivty